# Is it possible to add a new column with Rails generator to an arbitrary position of an existing table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's consider the case where I decide to add an `isbn` column to the already existing `Book` table, with Rails:

```
Book name:string (and implicitly, created_at:date, updated_at:date)
```

From what I've seen, it's an easy task to undertake provided we are fine with the fact the column to add will come out last. But what if I'd prefer to have it just after `name`, for instance? Despite being an almost entirely irrelevant matter from a Rails' point of view, I was curious, nonetheless, as I sometimes peek directly the database with other tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a Rails migration, using the `after` option:

```
add_column :books, :isbn, :string, :after => :name
```

You can also say `:first => true` to insert the new column as the first one.

Comment: I believe this will only work with MySQL, not SQLite or Postgres.

Comment: You're right. It was a [patch](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3286-patch-add-support-for-mysql-column-positioning-to-migrations) for MySQL.